# Cannot read property 'myHub' of undefined (SignalR)

Tags: javascript

i am getting error "Cannot read property 'myHub' of undefined" for Javascript trying to connect client to server through SignalR application .
myHub.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR;
using Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Hubs;

namespace ChatForm
{
    [HubName("myHub")]
    public class MyHub : Hub
    {
        public void addChat(string message)
        {
            Clients.All.addChat(message);
        }
    }
}
```

chat.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Chat";
}
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>
<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>
<div class="container">
    <input type="text" id="message" placeholder="Share what's in your mind..." />
    <input type="button" id="sendmessage" value="Send" />
    <br />
    <br />
    <label  id="label1">Group Chat Conversations History</label>
    <div>
        <input type="hidden" id="displayname" />
        <ul id="discussion"></ul>
    </div>   
</div>
@section scripts {

    <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="~/signalr/hub"></script>
    <script src="~/Scripts/chat.js"></script>

}
```

chat.js
making proxy
    $.connection.myHub.logging = true;

```
$.connection.myHub.start()
    .done(function () {
        console.log("Worked")

    })
    .fail(function () { alert("Error!!") });
```

Answer (score 2):

Your error means that `$.connection` is undefined. The question is why?

I think you forgot to load jquery. Try to load jquery bundle before signalR.

Answer (score 2):

I checked your code examples it tries to load `jquery.signalR-2.1.0.min.js` but jQuery is not added. Try to load jQuery as **@Jimmy Grande** said.

Also, check some other `C#` SignalR tutorials so you get more insights into the workings of SignalR as this can be tricky sometimes:

[ASP.NET SignalR Hubs Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/aspnet/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/hubs-api-guide-javascript-client)

[Introduction to SignalR](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/880963/Introduction-to-SignalR)